# Mi código no funciona de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

En el libro me pide "Todo lo que hemos estado haciendo hasta ahora se puede hacer con objetos. Deberíamos probarlo. ¿Qué tal un objeto que tenga un método que retorne
la tabla de multiplicar de un número?". Pero al ponerlo al objeto con su método, no me funciona.

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Tabla:
  def __init__(self, numero, nombre):
    self.numero = numero
    self.nombre = nombre

  def tabla1(self):
    print("Tabla de multiplicar del " + str(numero))
    print("Impresa automáticamente por " + nombre)
    i = 0
    while i < 11:
      print(str(numero) + " X " + str(i) + " = " + str(numero * i))
      i += 1

class Tablax(Tabla):
  def resultado(self):
    print("gracias")

tabla_multiplicar = Tablax(1, "Juan")

tabla_multiplicar.tabla1()

input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro del método `tabla1`, la variable `numero` no hace referencia a la propiedad del objeto. Para que lo haga simplemente tienes que reemplazar `numero` por `self.numero`. Lo mismo con `nombre` -> `self.nombre`.

```py
def tabla1(self):
  print("Tabla de multiplicar del " + str(self.numero))
  print("Impresa automáticamente por " + self.nombre))
  i = 0
    while i < 11:
      print(str(self.numero) + " X " + str(i) + " = " + str(self.numero * i))
      i += 1
```